# Why the ui elements are shared between view controllers in swift programmatic way?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I was trying to navigate view controllers in a programmatic approach in swift. So, my purpose in this test is

- Create two view controllers.
- Navigate between view controllers when a button is pressed

So this is my `AppDelegate.swift`. I created Navigation controller and embedded `ViewController`.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

        let navigationController = UINavigationController();
        let mainViewController = ViewController();
        let loginViewController = LoginViewController();
        navigationController.viewControllers = [ mainViewController, loginViewController ];
        self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController;
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }
```

Then in View Controller

```
let button: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 120, y: 120, width: 50, height: 50));
        button.setTitle("Login", for: .normal);
        button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor;
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red;
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 5;

        return button;
    }();

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white;
        view.addSubview(button);


        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(loginPressed(_sender:)), for: .touchUpInside);
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func loginPressed(_sender: UIButton) {
        print("clicked");
        let loginViewController = LoginViewController();
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(loginViewController, animated: true);
    }
```

And in `LoginViewController`

```
let emailLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 150, y: 150, width: 150, height: 150));
        label.text = "Email address";
        return label;
    }();

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(emailLabel);
        print("this is loginViewController");
    }
```

Here's my result. in ViewController

[image]

And in LoginViewController . 
[image]

So here's my question: Why the button is showing up in the loginViewController? Why the uielement has been shared between view controllers ?

NOTE: I tried searching in google. Maybe because I am a web developer, I might not have searched with the right words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the *exact* code you've posted, the initial view will be your `LoginViewController` (not your "Main" view controller) and the screen will be black.

So, to fix what you have there...

In `AppDelegate` don't try to create the `LoginViewController` - create and set only your "main" VC:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    let navigationController = UINavigationController();
    let mainViewController = ViewController();

    // don't try to create login view here...
    //let loginViewController = LoginViewController();
    //navigationController.viewControllers = [ mainViewController, loginViewController ];

    // set only your first controller
    navigationController.viewControllers = [ mainViewController ];

    self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController;
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

Now, the initial view when you run the app will show your "main" VC with the `Login` button... however, tapping that button will push to a black screen, because you didn't give `LoginViewController` a background color:

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    let emailLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 150, y: 150, width: 150, height: 150));
        label.text = "Email address";
        return label;
    }();

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // set background to green, to make it really obvious
        view.backgroundColor = .green

        view.addSubview(emailLabel);
        print("this is loginViewController");
    }
}
```

If you still see the `Login` button along with the email label, and / or the background is not green, I suspect you started by laying out your view controllers in Storyboard but did not clear the `Main Interface` in project settings (General tab):

[image]

If the `Main Interface` box is not blank, delete what's there and run your app again (with the above changes).

---

**EDIT**

Here is a complete example, using your code with the edits I described.

- Create a new Project
- ***Delete*** `Main.storyboard`
- Copy and Paste the `AppDelegate` code below into `AppDelegate.swift`
- Copy and Paste the `ViewController` code below into `ViewController.swift`
- Delete the word `Main` from `Main Interface` in project settings / General
- Run the app

See if you get what you want.

---

**AppDelegate**

```
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  NewProject
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 8/6/19.
//

import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

        let navigationController = UINavigationController();
        let mainViewController = ViewController();

        // don't try to create login view here...
        //let loginViewController = LoginViewController();
        //navigationController.viewControllers = [ mainViewController, loginViewController ];

        // set only your first controller
        navigationController.viewControllers = [ mainViewController ];

        self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController;
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }
    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }
    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }
    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }
    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }
    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }
}
```

---

**ViewController**

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  NewProject
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 8/7/19.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let button: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 120, y: 120, width: 50, height: 50));
        button.setTitle("Login", for: .normal);
        button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor;
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red;
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 5;

        return button;
    }();

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white;
        view.addSubview(button);


        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(loginPressed(_sender:)), for: .touchUpInside);
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func loginPressed(_sender: UIButton) {
        print("clicked");
        let loginViewController = LoginViewController();
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(loginViewController, animated: true);
    }

}

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    let emailLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 150, y: 150, width: 150, height: 150));
        label.text = "Email address";
        return label;
    }();

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .green
        view.addSubview(emailLabel);
        print("this is loginViewController");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried and unfrotunately it didn't work. I set the background color to make it obvious and I still see the login button alongside with email label with the background color i set.

Comment: @KyawSiesein - try it with a new project. See the edit to my answer.

Comment: I got it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First try to debug with backgroundColor and check if maybe the view is transparent.

Second remove the `loginViewController` from `navigationController.viewControllers = [ mainViewController, loginViewController ];` because with this you are pushing an UIViewController to the stack.

You are creating a new instance of LoginViewController anyways when you push with `let loginViewController = LoginViewController();`

When you print your `navigationController.viewControllers` after the push you will have something like `[mainViewController, loginViewController, loginViewController]` I think this is not what you want.

Third, @IBAction is for Storyboard. Why you are not using Storyboard in generell? What you want to achieve is possible within a few clicks and without one line of code.

Comment: I tried with the backgroundColor check and I can still see the button in `loginViewController`. Secondly, I have removed `loginViewController` from `viewController stack`. Thanks for the info (I understand that now). But if i dont add action, do i have to add @objc? otherwise this error pops up. `Argument of '#selector' refers to instance method 'loginPressed(_sender:)' that is not exposed to Objective-C`

Comment: Yes, just use "@objc" instead of "@IBOutlet"

Comment: Thanks. Do you have an idea why the uielement is sharing across the view controllers? I tried both of you and the below answer, it didn't work.

Comment: The thing is, the uielements are not get shared in generell, except you inherit from it. So it has to be something different.

Answer (score 0):

After spending more time and looking for what I did wrong from @DonMag's answer, the view controller I was trying to push is inheriting the `ViewController` class instead of actual `UIViewController`.